# React router appends page at last when routing

Tags: javascript, meteor, react-router

I have two components, {App} and {Blog}, when I was trying to route to Blog page from App, actually the Blog page content was appended at the last of App page. How can I jump to the blog page from App page?

Routing:

```
const routes = (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Route path="/" component={App}/>
      <Route path="blog" component={Blog}/>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);


Meteor.startup(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(routes, document.querySelector(".render-target"));
});
```

Blog.js:

```
class Blog extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>Blog</div>
    );
  };
}

export default Blog;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the Switch component from react-router. This will make sure that the first route matches inside.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="blog" component={Blog}/>
      <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

As you can see in the example, put the blog route before the /. If you put the / route as your first route it will match this one on any other route and stop there.

For more info, check out [this piece](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md)